# Recursive method to return a set of all combinations

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

Can someone explain me how this code works? Is it possible to be written in another way? I tried it with just `ArrayList` but cannot figure it out.

```
public static Set<Set<Integer>> combinations(List<Integer> groupSize, int k) {
    Set<Set<Integer>> allCombos = new HashSet<Set<Integer>> ();

    // base cases for recursion
    if (k == 0) {
        // There is only one combination of size 0, the empty team.
        allCombos.add(new HashSet<Integer>());
        return allCombos;
    }
    if (k > groupSize.size()) {
        // There can be no teams with size larger than the group size,
        // so return allCombos without putting any teams in it.
        return allCombos;
    }

    // Create a copy of the group with one item removed.
    List<Integer> groupWithoutX = new ArrayList<Integer> (groupSize);
    Integer x = groupWithoutX.remove(groupWithoutX.size()-1);

    Set<Set<Integer>> combosWithoutX = combinations(groupWithoutX, k);
    Set<Set<Integer>> combosWithX = combinations(groupWithoutX, k-1);
    for (Set<Integer> combo : combosWithX) {
        combo.add(x);
    }
    allCombos.addAll(combosWithoutX);
    allCombos.addAll(combosWithX);
    return allCombos;
}
```

Comment: Try here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This isn't recursive.  Did you mean `combinations` instead of `showTeam`?

Comment: yes combinations! sorry for the mistake

Comment: Because of that mistake, someone assumed that your code was not recursive and removed the mention of recursion in your question. Please consider fixing the mistake as well as putting back the "recursive" tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
The code returns a set of integer sets with all possible combinations of the integers in the first given set with k integers. I'll just demonstrate what it does with the case with list = [1,2,3] and k = 2.

groupWithoutX = [1,2].
x = 1.
k = 2.

Then, in the call combinations(groupWithoutX, k), the second base case is true, so the method just returns [1,2].


In the other recursive call, the recursion happens again.

groupWithoutX = [1].
x = 2.
k = 1.

The first call returns 1.
The second call returns an empty set.
However, x must be added to this empty set, so it becomes 2.

The second recursive call of the initial call of the method, then, returns a set of the sets of integers: [1] [2]

Back at the first call of the method, x = 3 must be added to each of the sets the second recursive call. [1] becomes [1,3] and [2] becomes [2,3].

The method returns all three created sets: [1,2] [1,3] [2,3].

In other words, this method is similar to the combination (nCr) in math, except it returns the sets created rather than just the number of sets.
```

Comment: You need some sort of collection. It can be any type, but sets are most logical because you don't want more than one of the same element in the set and you don't care about the order.